# two combos, jquery select plugin work in certain condition only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two combos in my asp.net mvc razor view.

```
<select id="country_id" ... />
```

and

```
<select id="city_id" ... />
```

When country_id option is selected then second combo (`city_id`) is populated with certain data.
Before it's populated I first remove option values from this second combo.

Just to mention that this functionality works properly. Now I want to apply some styles to my
combos. I decided to use [SelectBoxIt by Greg Franko.](http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/)

**Problem desc.**
On initial render first combo is rendered with applied selectboxit plugin. On `#country_id` changed
second combo is populated with expected values and plugin is correctly applied.

> Problem arises when I second time change #country_id and select any
>   option value.  Second combo (#city_id) stays intact, doesn't change
>   anything (stays on previous selection).

When I remove

```
 $("#city_id").selectBoxIt();
```

from my updateData js function everything works fine (but this time without plugin applied to second combo).

```
/****** JS FILE ************/
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#country_id").change(function () {
        updateData(new FilteredData($("#country_id :selected").val());
    });
})

function updateData(fdata) {    
    $.ajax({
        url: formatUrl('/.....'),
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(fdata),
        success: function (result) {            
            var dropDown = $("#city_id");
            // clear all previous options                        
            $("#city_id > option").remove();
            // populate the cities
            for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                dropDown.append($("<option />").val(result[i].Id).text(result[i].Name));                
            }
            ...
            $("#city_id").selectBoxIt();
        }
        ...
}

function FilteredData(country)
{
    this.country = country;
}

*************** _Layout.cshtml ***************
....
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#country_id").selectBoxIt();
    })
</script>
```

http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add elements, you're using

```
dropDown.append($("<option />").val(result[i].Id).text(result[i].Name));
```

which, as you've noted, works fine for standard HTML.

For SelectBoxIt, a different code is need per [their documentation](http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/#DynamicallyAddOptions)

```
dropDown.data("selectBox-selectBoxIt").add({ value: result[i].Id, text: result[i].Name });
```

And, don't forget the remove all options code:

```
dropDown.data("selectBox-selectBoxIt").remove();
```

It's always a good idea to check the API documentation for any plugins you use as they all have their own way of doing things. :)